# Is there a Python module/(function) that could set the number of CPUs for a dsl ContainerOp (Kubeflow pipelines)?

Tags: python, kubeflow

I've built a Jupyter notebook that deploys a Jupyter notebook into the Kubeflow pipeline service as a component of the pipeline. I want to know if there is a way to specify the number of CPU's and memory for the ContainerOp that deploys the notebook.

GOAL: to have cpu and mem show up as parameters in the yaml file when I open up and read the tar.gz file's contents

I've tried using the multiprocessing library but the sample of code I'm publishing (paths and images hidden) looks too idiotic to be correct. Plus that's not what my boss wants

```
    import kfp
    import random
    import string
    if not os.path.exists(tmp_dir):
        os.makedirs(tmp_dir)
    def demo_op(input_notebook, output_notebook, name):
        return dsl.ContainerOp(
            name='papermill',
            image=image,
            command=['sh', '-c'],
            pvolumes={"/home/jovyan": dsl.PipelineVolume(pvc="efs-storage",name='efs-storage')},
            arguments=['papermill $0 $1 -p name $2', input_notebook, output_notebook, name] 
        )

    @dsl.pipeline(
        name='papermill demo',
        description='executing notebooks demo'
    )
    def pipeline_func(output_notebook,
                      name,
                      input_notebook='abcd'):  #example of path 

        demo_task = demo_op(input_notebook, output_notebook, name)

    filename = tmp_dir + '/demo{dt:%Y%m%d_%H%M%S}.pipeline.tar.gz'.format(dt=datetime.datetime.now())
    compiler.Compiler().compile(pipeline_func, filename)
    client = kfp.Client()
    experiment = client.create_experiment('papermill_volume_test')
arguments = {'output_notebook': 'abcd', #example
                 'name': 'demo_test'} # Output_notebook prints: demo_test
run_name = 'papermill demo run'
run_result = client.run_pipeline(experiment.id, run_name, filename, arguments)

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_func, args=(tmp_dr, 
        image, inp_nb, out_np, mem))
processes.append(p)
p.start()

for d in processes:
    d.join()
```

This won't give the number of cpu's used in the yaml file

Answer (score 3):

You can apply cpu and memory limits on the pod directly via the ContainerOp object at compile time with:

```
demo_op.set_memory_limit('4G')
demo_op.set_cpu_limit('4.0')
```

before calling the ContainerOp with, `demo_op(input_notebook, output_notebook, name)`

Here's the link to the KFP SDK calling k8s resources based on limit: [link](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/sdk/python/kfp/dsl/_container_op.py#L256-L276)

This also shows up in the compiled Argo yaml:

```
- container:
      .....
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: '4.0'
          memory: 4Gi
```